# R ggplot - Combine boxplot and dotplot in absence of x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the price of items via a combined boxplot and dotplot.

```
ggplot(data=Item, aes(y = price/1000)) + ylab("Price (x10^3)") + geom_boxplot(, outlier.shape=1, outlier.size=3) + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center')
```

I am getting an error

> Error: stat_bindot requires the following missing aesthetics: x

which is due to me not specifying an x axis within aes. However I would like all of the plots to be in the center on the x axis in line with the boxplot outliers.

What should I specify as the x axis so it is "ignored"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just needed to set x = 1

```
ggplot(data=Item, aes(y = price/1000, x = 1)) + ylab("Price (x10^3)") + geom_boxplot(, outlier.shape=1, outlier.size=3) + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center')
```